# HTML Box Model Not Right

Tags: html, css

Box model has always given me a headache. I am taking a template ([here](http://themeforest.net/item/cupcake-premium-admin-template-mobile-theme/full_screen_preview/1296055)) and integrating it into a Spring MVC + Apache Tiles project ([here](http://24.210.38.163/Services)). When I look in Firebug, I can see that the `main` div is not wrapping its contents properly. Below is the outermost parts of the HTML. I apologize for not putting more code here, but the live site (showing the problem) hopefully makes up for it (log in with admin/admin).

```
<html>
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="header"> ... </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="sidebar"> ... </div>
                <div id="page"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** This has been solved, so I have taken my demo offline.

Comment: It looks normal for me in Windows 7 - Firefox 11.

Comment: It doesn't look normal in my Firefox 11 (OS X) and the CSS is spread across multiple files. The point of the HTML was to quickly indicate where I think the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#main` is defined in *root.css*. I think you just need to trigger that div to expand to cover it's children. You can do so by adding an `overflow:auto; zoom:1;` to the ruleset.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. To expand... `#sidebar` and `#page` are floated and not being cleared. Adding `overflow: hidden` will clear them. Make sure **not** to include an explicit height on `#main` though.

Comment: And this is why I don't like to use other people's templates, but sometimes I can't get around it.

Comment: @steveax Thanks - I was just about to add that. :)